# Get "firefox is already running" after upgrade to 21.10

Tags: upgrade, firefox, snap

So I just upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10, and everything seems to work fine except for firefox not wanting to start.
There are no processes for firefox running, so not sure why I get this error.

I believe it was installed through apt before the upgrade.
I have tried to reinstall firefox, and install the beta-track.
I have tried to reboot the computer. It took a while to shut down.

Any suggestions for what i should try to fix this is highly appreciated!

Comment: perhaps remove either the apt or the snap version if you have no reason to have both co-existing. Does the apt version still run? Have you set up a FF account to preserve your settings? Was the apt version still running when you performed the upgrade. Please [edit] your question with further details.

Comment: Has rebooting computer fixed it? Sometimes I get similar situation, rebooting always worked.

Comment: I forgot to mention what i have tried. Updated the post.